# Arrangement of arrays such that maximum number of elements are greater in one array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Assuming I have two arrays A and B (Both with equal number of elements)

```
int A[] = {40,50,70};
int B[] = {80,60,45};
```

I have to rearrange array A in such a way that maximum number of elements in Array A are greater than their respective elements in array B.

In this case, rearranging A as {40,70,50} would yield the required result.

What would be the most optimal way of going this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your attempt(s) and maybe somebody here will offer a way to fix or improve your code.

Comment: Start with the best approach you can think of. Write it. Run it. Is it fast enough? If not, look for patterns you can use to reduce the amount of work that needs to be performed. Don't worry about optimal until your approach has been proved to be too slow.

Comment: @pmg yes, we can sort them

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why your answer is `{40,70,50}`, when 40 is less than 80.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: there are no values bigger than 80, and 40 is smaller than 45 anyway.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
It is in that order because, 40<80, 70>60, 50>45 . In this case, two elements in A are greater than their respective elements in B. it can also be rearranged as

Comment: Take bigger value from A, place it to the biggest value less than A value. Repeat the process until all remaining A value are too small, place remaining in any order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use something like:

```
std::vector<int> f(std::vector<int> A, const std::vector<int>& B)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> indexes(B.size());
    std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0);

    std::sort(A.begin(), A.end(), std::greater<>{});
    std::sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(),
              [&B](std::size_t lhs, std::size_t rhs){ return B[lhs] > B[rhs]; });

    auto it = A.begin();
    auto rit = A.rbegin();
    std::vector<int> res(A.size());
    for (auto index : indexes) {
        if (*it > B[index]) {
            res[index] = *it;
            ++it;
        } else {
            res[index] = *rit;
            ++rit;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8f9052ca3e8d539)

Complexity: `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Thanks
I did something like what you mentioned in your comment. It worked. But this is much efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we can also rearrange B for now. Clearly, it's always optimal to match the largest elements in A to lesser elements in B. Therefore, we can iterate over elements in A in decreasing order and try to pair them with lesser elements in B.

For each element in A, we'll want to use the greatest unused element in B which is less than the element in A, since we want to save the smaller elements in B for use later. We can sort B and find this element using binary search or by maintaining a pointer to the greatest unused element. If at any point we can't find an unused element in B that is less than the next element in A, we know that we won't be able to match the rest of the elements in A to lesser elements in B so we can match the remaining elements arbitrarily. Now we can rearrange the pairs so that the elements in B will be in their original order and we have a solution.