# How to find an order of list such that its elements are greater than the corresponding elements in second list. I have to maximize such number

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting, optimization

It fails one test case out of 11.

Given 2 lists, I have to find order in 1st list such that the corresponding elements in second list are of less magnitude.

So for example:
If list 1 has elements `[10, 40, 30]` and list 2 has elements `[20,5,50]`
Here only `40` in list 1 is greater than corresponding `5` in list 2. A correct order in list 1 to maximize such order would be `[30,40,10]`, now 2 elements are greater than the corresponding elements in list 2.

Note that it should be strictly greater.

My approach:

1. So what I did was create a list of tuples, such that each tuple represents a number from the list and the list it belongs to.
2. And then I sorted this list based on the numbers in the tuples.
3. Iterate through the list and every pair of tuples, if say element in list 1 is `t1` and element in list 2 is `t2`, then if `t1` occurs after `t2` then we have a match (Since this `t1` would be greater than `t2`, (I added a case when there will be equality, in this case it will treat is simply as `t1 = t2` and continue looping).
4. Update the index parameters and the count for a successful match.

```
    def main(t1,t2):
        tn = []

        # Make a list of tuples such that each tuple is of the form (number, list it belongs to)
        # so if a number belongs to t1, say 5. So the tuple will look like (5,t1)

        for i,j in zip(t1,t2):
                tn.append((i,'t1'))
                tn.append((j,'t2'))

        # Sort this tuple on the basis of numbers
        tn = sorted(tn, key = lambda a: a[0]) 
        wins = 0

        t1_ind = 0
        t2_ind = 0

       # Implementation of point 3 from here
        while True:
            if t1_ind > t2_ind: # The t1 index should always be greater than t2 index for a match
                if tn[t2_ind][1] == 't2':

                    # An edge case for equal numbers, these won't be greater even if t1 occurs after t2

                    if tn[t1_ind][1] == 't1' and tn[t1_ind][0] != tn[t2_ind][0]: 
                        # We have a successful match here and hence we update the win count
                        wins += 1
                        t2_ind += 1  # Move t2's index ahead as we have a match
                    t1_ind += 1  # In any case if we find t2 and do an analysis, t1's index should move ahead
                else:
                   # if we don't find t2 and t2_index, then move ahead
                    t2_ind += 1
            else:
            # Update index of t1, as t1's index is <= t2's index now
                t1_ind += 1
            if t1_ind >= len(tn) - 1:
                break

        return wins
```

**Its throwing error and I can't figure out what is wrong. It is passing 10/11 test cases. There is nothing shown about that 1 edge case, apart from the fact that it took 4 seconds to run and fails**

This goes in `O( n Log n)`.  If there is a better approach or optimization possible then I would like to know.

I found a similar post, but it's in C++ and there is no explanation so I can't make sense of the logic. 
[Similar Problem In C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160415/arrangement-of-arrays-such-that-maximum-number-of-elements-are-greater-in-one-ar)

***Edit: Some extra points about my approach as some suggest that the approach is not directly intuitive.***

For 2 lists, the algorithm is merging them and sorting them. 
After merging and sorting, for example, The order of elements is:

`1 3 4 5 5 6....`

So now, we store which element belongs to which list: (l1 for list 1 and l2 for list2)

`l1 l2 l1 l1 l2 l1 ....`

We now start iterating from left, and look for elements `l1 occurring after l2`, the numbers corresponding to `l1` will definitely be greater than the number corresponding to least unmatched `l2`, we greedily make such pairs and increase the count for each match, marking each matched pair.

Comment: I'm just wondering.., what if you sorted two list according to ascending order and then superpose and write cases for incorrect/out of order datasets?

Comment: I'm confused. Your problem description sounds like you want to find the optimal ordering, but your code makes no attempt to return any ordering information; rather, it just returns a `wins` count.

Comment: @FMc The wins count is triggered for every `match` in an optimal ordering. I am just not printing it. `tn[t1_index][0]` and `tn[t2_index][0]` is the corresponding optimal ordering.

Comment: @Agent_Orange Superimposing won't be optimal. For ex: `[40,50,70]` and `[80,60,45]`, when sorted will give `[45,60,80]` and 0 matches, but in fact there are 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sort both lists A and B (O(nlogn))

Make indices Aidx = 0, Bidx = 0

While A[Aidx] <= B[Bidx] increment Aidx

When A[Aidx] becomes larger than B[Bidx] - increment "wins" and increment both indices

Repeat until A end  (O(n) stage)
```

Code

```
import random
A = [random.randrange(1, 100) for _ in range(random.randrange(3, 10))]
B = [random.randrange(1, 100) for _ in range(random.randrange(3, 10))]
A.sort()
B.sort()
wins = 0
ia = 0
ib = 0
while ia < len(A) and ib < len(B):
    while ia < len(A) and A[ia] <= B[ib]:
        ia += 1
    if ia < len(A):
        wins += 1
        ia += 1
        ib += 1
print(A)
print(B)
print(wins)

[4, 5, 22, 30, 43, 55, 78, 80]
[19, 54, 85, 95]
2

[16, 17, 23, 26, 29, 34, 48, 98]
[6, 43, 65]
3
```